# Unable to create Ec2 instance with autoscaling and register them to ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, autoscaling, aws-application-load-balancer

Hi I am trying to create a cluster with service and task. I have a python app in Ecr that connects to redis container. The issue is I am unable to create ec2 instance with autoscaling. `Myservice` in Cluster and Autoscaling doesn't builds.

Cluster:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09 
Parameters:
    Alb:
      Type: String
    DefaultTargetGroup:
      Type: String
    ECSServiceRole:
      Type: String
    Task:
      Type: String
Resources:
    MyCluster:
        Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
        Properties: 
            ClusterName: Flask-redis
    Myservice:
        Type: AWS::ECS::Service
        Properties: 
            Cluster: !Ref MyCluster        
            DeploymentController:   
                Type: ECS
            DesiredCount: 2
            LaunchType: EC2
            LoadBalancers: 
                - ContainerName: python
                  ContainerPort: 5000
                  TargetGroupArn: !Ref DefaultTargetGroup
            Role: !Ref ECSServiceRole
            SchedulingStrategy: REPLICA
            ServiceName: Python-service
            TaskDefinition: !Ref Task
```

Autoscaling:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  SubnetA:
    Type: String
  SubnetB:
    Type: String
  VpcID:
    Type: String
  Albsg:
    Type: String
  Alb:
    Type: String
  ECSServiceRole:
    Type: String

Resources:
  wahajwebserver:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: wahaj-webserver
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref Albsg
          Description: For traffic from Internet
      GroupDescription: Security Group for demo server
      VpcId: !Ref VpcID
  ec2instance:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
    #   UserData:
    #     Fn::Base64: !Sub |
    #     #!/bin/bash -xe
    #     echo ECS_CLUSTER=${ECSCluster} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
    #     yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
    #     /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource ECSAutoScalingGroup --region ${AWS::Region}
        BlockDeviceMappings:
          - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
            Ebs:
                DeleteOnTermination: "true"
                VolumeSize: "8"
                VolumeType: gp2
        ImageId: ami-0bdcc6c05dec346bf
        InstanceType: t2.small
        IamInstanceProfile: !Ref ECSServiceRole
        KeyName: wahaj(webserver)
        SecurityGroups:
            - Ref: wahajwebserver
  myASG:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
        AvailabilityZones:
            - "us-east-2a"
            - "us-east-2b"
        AutoScalingGroupName: myASG
        LoadBalancerNames:
            - Ref: Alb
        MinSize: "2"
        MaxSize: "2"
        DesiredCapacity: "2"
        HealthCheckGracePeriod: 300
        LaunchConfigurationName:
            Ref: ec2instance
        VPCZoneIdentifier:
            - Ref: "SubnetA"
            - Ref: "SubnetB"
```

Task:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09 
Parameters:
    ExRole:
        Type: String
Resources:
    Task:
        Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
        Properties:
            Family: redis-python 
            Cpu: 1 vCPU
            ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExRole
            Memory: 1 GB
            NetworkMode: bridge
            RequiresCompatibilities:
                - EC2
            TaskRoleArn: !Ref ExRole
            ContainerDefinitions: 
              - Essential: true
                Image: redis:latest
                Name: redis 
              - Essential: true
                Image: 021146125185.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/python-app:latest
                Name: python
                PortMappings:  
                  - ContainerPort: 5000
                    HostPort: 0
                    Protocol: tcp
                DependsOn:
                   - Condition: START  
                     ContainerName: redis
                Links: 
                   - redis            
Outputs:
  Task:
    Description: Contains all the task specifications
    Value: !Ref Task
    Export:
      Name: "Task"
```

Application Load balancer:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
    SubnetA:
      Type: String
    SubnetB:
      Type: String
    VpcID:
      Type: String
Resources:
    Albsg:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
        Properties:
            GroupName: alb-sg
            VpcId: !Ref VpcID
            SecurityGroupIngress:
                - IpProtocol: tcp
                  FromPort: 22
                  ToPort: 22
                  CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
                  Description: For traffic from Internet
                - IpProtocol: tcp
                  FromPort: 80
                  ToPort: 80
                  CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
                  Description: For traffic from Internet
            GroupDescription: Security Group for demo server
    Alb:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
        Properties: 
            IpAddressType: ipv4
            Name: Alb
            Scheme: internet-facing
            SecurityGroups: 
                - !Ref Albsg
            Subnets:
                - Ref: "SubnetA"
                - Ref: "SubnetB"
            Type: application
    DefaultTargetGroup:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
        DependsOn: Alb
        Properties:
            Name: alb-tg
            VpcId: !Ref VpcID
            Port: 80
            Protocol: HTTP
    LoadBalancerListener:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
        Properties:
            LoadBalancerArn: !Ref Alb
            Port: 80
            Protocol: HTTP
            DefaultActions:
                - Type: forward
                  TargetGroupArn: !Ref DefaultTargetGroup
Outputs:
  Albsg:
    Description: security group for application load balancer
    Value: !Ref Albsg
    Export:
        Name: "Albsg"
  Alb:
    Description: application load balancer
    Value: !Ref Alb
    Export:
      Name: "Alb"
  DefaultTargetGroup:
    Description: Default Target Group
    Value: !Ref DefaultTargetGroup
    Export:
      Name: "DefaultTargetGroup"
```

role:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09 
Resources:
    ECSServiceRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service: [ecs.amazonaws.com]
              Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
          Path: /
          Policies:
          - PolicyName: ecs-service
            PolicyDocument:
              Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: ['elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer', 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets',
                  'elasticloadbalancing:Describe*', 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer',
                  'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets', 'ec2:Describe*', 'ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress']
                Resource: '*'
    ExRole:
        Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
        Properties:
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Principal:
                  Service:
                    - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
                Action:
                  - 'sts:AssumeRole'
          Path: /
          ManagedPolicyArns:
            - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
          Policies: 
            - PolicyName: AccessECR
              PolicyDocument:
                Version: '2012-10-17'
                Statement:
                  - Effect: Allow
                    Action: 
                      - ecr:BatchGetImage
                      - ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
                      - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer 
                    Resource: '*'
Outputs:
  ExRole:
    Description: Task excution role
    Value: !Ref ExRole
    Export:
        Name: "ExRole"
  ECSServiceRole:
    Description: application load balancer
    Value: !Ref ECSServiceRole
    Export:
      Name: "ECSServiceRole"
```

I am unable to create Ec2 instance with autoscaling and register them to ECS cluster. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any error messages, the initial look at `Autoscaling` template shows several issues.

#### LoadBalancerNames

```
        LoadBalancerNames:
            - Ref: Alb
```

This is only for CLB, but you are using ALB. For ALB you should be using [TargetGroupARNs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-targetgrouparns) parameter.

#### UserData

You commented  out the `UserData`. Not sure why? It should be there as you should register the instance with the cluster. I guess due to mistakes? see below.

#### cfn-signal

In the UserData, you are using `--resource ECSAutoScalingGroup`. But it should be `--resource myASG`

#### ASG and creation policy

`cfn-signal` has no effect as your ASG is missing [CreationPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html).

#### ECSCluster

Again in the `UserData`: reference to `ECSCluster` is not defined.

#### ImageId

Just by looking at `ami-0bdcc6c05dec346bf` I'm not sure if this is ECS optimized AMI. This have to be checked.

#### ECSServiceRole

Its form is not shown. Could be incorrect or even fully missing.

## Update and fixed template

Upon further examination many more issues were found. Just to name few:

- missing instance profile
- missing/wrong container instance role
- incorrect security groups
- Not using `ImportValue`
- Missing some output exports

The fixed and modified templates was tested in `us-east-1` and default VPC. It will not work in any other region unless AMI is adjusted. Also due to lack of your ECR image, I had to create my own with my own ports, so I also had to modify this as well to even attempt a verification.

**roles**

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09 
Resources:

  ExRole:
      Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
              Action:
                - 'sts:AssumeRole'
        Path: /
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
        Policies: 
          - PolicyName: AccessECR
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action: 
                    - ecr:BatchGetImage
                    - ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
                    - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer 
                  Resource: '*'

  ContainerInstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'               
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: {'Service': ['ec2.amazonaws.com']}
            Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role
      Path: '/'

  InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties: 
      Roles: 
        - !Ref ContainerInstanceRole      

Outputs:
  
  ExRole:
    Description: Task excution role
    Value: !Ref ExRole
    Export:
        Name: "ExRole"


  InstanceProfile:
    Description: profile for container instances
    Value: !Ref InstanceProfile
    Export:
        Name: "InstanceProfile"
```

**alb**

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
    SubnetA:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
    SubnetB:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
    VpcID:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
Resources:
    Albsg:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
        Properties:
            GroupName: alb-sg
            VpcId: !Ref VpcID
            SecurityGroupIngress:
                - IpProtocol: tcp
                  FromPort: 80
                  ToPort: 80
                  CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
                  Description: For traffic from Internet
            GroupDescription: Security Group for demo server
    Alb:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
        Properties: 
            IpAddressType: ipv4
            Name: Alb
            Scheme: internet-facing
            SecurityGroups: 
                - !Ref Albsg
            Subnets:
                - Ref: "SubnetA"
                - Ref: "SubnetB"
            Type: application
    DefaultTargetGroup:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
        DependsOn: Alb
        Properties:
            Name: alb-tg
            VpcId: !Ref VpcID
            Port: 8080
            Protocol: HTTP
    LoadBalancerListener:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
        Properties:
            LoadBalancerArn: !Ref Alb
            Port: 80
            Protocol: HTTP
            DefaultActions:
                - Type: forward
                  TargetGroupArn: !Ref DefaultTargetGroup
Outputs:
  Albsg:
    Description: security group for application load balancer
    Value: !Ref Albsg
    Export:
        Name: "Albsg"
  Alb:
    Description: application load balancer
    Value: !Ref Alb
    Export:
      Name: "Alb"
  DefaultTargetGroup:
    Description: Default Target Group
    Value: !Ref DefaultTargetGroup
    Export:
      Name: "DefaultTargetGroup"

  SubnetA:
    Value: !Ref SubnetA
    Export:
        Name: "SubnetA"
  SubnetB:
    Value: !Ref SubnetB
    Export:
        Name: "SubnetB"
  VpcID:
    Value: !Ref VpcID
    Export:
        Name: "VpcID"
```

**task**

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09 

Resources:
    Task:
        Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
        Properties:
            Family: redis-python 
            Cpu: 1 vCPU
            ExecutionRoleArn: !ImportValue ExRole
            Memory: 1 GB
            NetworkMode: bridge
            RequiresCompatibilities:
                - EC2
            TaskRoleArn: !ImportValue ExRole
            ContainerDefinitions: 
              - Essential: true
                Image: redis:latest
                Name: redis 
              - Essential: true
                Image: xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxx:latest
                Name: python
                PortMappings:  
                  - ContainerPort: 8080
                    #HostPort: 0
                    Protocol: tcp
                DependsOn:
                   - Condition: START  
                     ContainerName: redis
                Links: 
                   - redis            
Outputs:
  Task:
    Description: Contains all the task specifications
    Value: !Ref Task
    Export:
      Name: "Task"
```

**service_and_asg**

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:

  KeyName:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Default: wahajwebserver

  DesiredCapacity:
    Type: Number
    Default: 2

  MinSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: 1

  MaxSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: 4  


Resources:

  MyCluster:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
      Properties: {}

  wahajwebserver:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      #GroupName: wahaj-webserver
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 0
          ToPort: 65535
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !ImportValue Albsg
          Description: For traffic from Internet
      GroupDescription: Security Group for demo server
      VpcId: !ImportValue VpcID

  Myservice:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Service
      Properties: 
          Cluster: !Ref MyCluster        
          DeploymentController:   
              Type: ECS
          DesiredCount: 2
          LaunchType: EC2
          LoadBalancers: 
              - ContainerName: python
                ContainerPort: 8080
                TargetGroupArn: !ImportValue DefaultTargetGroup
          #Role: !Ref ECSServiceRole
          SchedulingStrategy: REPLICA
          #ServiceName: Python-service
          TaskDefinition: !ImportValue Task

  ec2instance:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe

          yum update -y && yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap 

          echo ECS_CLUSTER=${MyCluster} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
          echo ECS_BACKEND_HOST= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config           

          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? \
                --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
                --resource myASG \
                --region ${AWS::Region}

      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: "true"
            VolumeSize: 30
            VolumeType: gp2
      ImageId: ami-07a63940735aebd38 # before ami-0bdcc6c05dec346bf
      InstanceType: t2.small
      IamInstanceProfile: !ImportValue InstanceProfile
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      SecurityGroups:
          - Ref: wahajwebserver

  myASG:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT5M
        Count: !Ref DesiredCapacity
    Properties:
      #AutoScalingGroupName: myASG
      MinSize: !Ref MinSize
      MaxSize: !Ref MaxSize
      DesiredCapacity: !Ref DesiredCapacity
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 300
      LaunchConfigurationName:
        Ref: ec2instance
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !ImportValue SubnetA
        - !ImportValue SubnetB
      TargetGroupARNs:
        - !ImportValue DefaultTargetGroup
```

## Screenshots showing an ECS cluster with two tasks and 2 tasks (1 task on each instance)

[image]

Comment: Thanks thats alot of changes I have to make, will update once I complete

Comment: @aws-noob No problem. I attempted to run the template, like before, but there are missing sections, such as `ExRole`? The role could also be not-defined at all, or incorrect.

Comment: I have added the role template in the question, I have created Exrole for taskexecution. It would be great if you could help me

Comment: @aws-noob I see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks! any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: @aws-noob Template fixed, but it was quite an exercise to fix it.

Comment: Thanks marcin for helping me out. The Ami is different for each region? I am running it on us-east-2

Comment: `Myserivce` section in `service_and_asg` template it is neccesary to give the role when loadbalancer is defined https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html#cfn-ecs-service-loadbalancers So in roles what should I give the `instanceprofile` role?

Comment: @aws-noob The role should be there already/ So ECS will use it. But you can also explicitly specify it. For instance profile you will use profile I created with `ContainerInstanceRole` role. The role is needed so that ECS agent on the instances have permissions to access ECS and ECR.

Comment: I am having an error I have created a new question for it, Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223217/unable-to-assume-role-and-validate-the-specified-targetgrouparn-please-verify-t